# Original derivation of the Dyson equation

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, theoretical-physics, quantum-field-theory, dyson

In what paper did Dyson derive the Dyson equation, as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy)?

Comment: Not sure but see F. Dyson: The S Matrix in Quantum Electrodynamics.  Phys. Rev.. 75, (1949), p.1736. doi:10.1103/PhysRev.75.1736.

Answer (score 3):

It is equation (63) in his epochal [second paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.75.1736), Dyson, F  J  (1949). *"The S matrix in quantum electrodynamics"*, *Phys Rev*  **75** (11), 1736.

He refers to his first one, but the systematics in momentum space of the reducible self energy Σ are there.